# Connect to remote node using moner-wallet-cli with --daemon-address with a password?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, daemon, remote-node

I'm trying to use my password protected remote node with the following cli command, but it doesn't work. What is the correct format to use a user/pass with the remote node in the cli?

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address  aaa:bbb@xxxxx.com:18089
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A login (username + password), if set on the daemon (via the `monerod --rpc-login` flag), has to be passed via the `--daemon-login` flag upon launching `monero-wallet-cli`. That is, `monero-wallet-cli --help` states:

```
--daemon-login arg          Specify username[:password] for daemon                                       RPC client
```

Thus, in your example, the login would be passed as follows:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --daemon-address <domain-or-ip-of-remote-node>:<port-of-remote-node> --daemon-login <username>:<password>
```